# Session Not setting after Login [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When i logged in to the site the session is not setting. It was working fine earlier but somehow it is not working now.

**My controller code:**

```
public function login_subadmin()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('Email');
        $password=sha1($this->input->post('Password'));
        $this->sb->login_sub_admin($email,$password);

    }
```

**My Model code:**

```
public function login_sub_admin($email,$password)
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $query=$this->db->where(['Email'=>$email,'Password'=>$password])->get('dc_user');
         $res=$query->row();
                $this->session->set_userdata('user',$res->Employee_Name);
        if(!isset($this->session->userdata['user']))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('user',"No session");
        }
                redirect(base_url());

    }
```

**My view Navigation:**

```
<?php
if(!isset($this->session->userdata['user']))
{
                         $this->session->set_userdata('user',"No session");?>
    <!-- Login -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="sub_Admin" class="nav-item-child radius-3">
            Login
        </a>

    </li>
    <!-- End Login -->

<?php }
if (isset($this->session->userdata['user'])) {$user=$this->session->userdata['user'];?>
    <!-- Home -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $user;?>&nbsp;<img style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" class="image-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profileimages/<?php if (isset($this->session->userdata['profile'])) {

                echo $this->session->userdata['profile'];


            }?>" alt="">
```

When i load the page / login into the site the it says `no session`. i use session library in autoload, and individually also but i don't know why it suddenly stops working, It was working fine the last time i close the project, i also clear my browser cache but still did not able to fix it, i have searched a lot and applied many steps / procedures on it but did not get the issue reason.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the sessions save path in config.php also autoloaed the session

Answer (score 3):

try below code

**Errors:**

> 1. **To access `profile` in session you need to set it**
> 2. **wrong declaration of the session** and few codes have been modified.
> 3. As well **Session setting part should move to the controller**.

---

**In Controller**

```
public function login_subadmin()
{
    $this->load->library('session');

    $email=$this->input->post('Email');
    $password=sha1($this->input->post('Password'));

    $result = $this->sb->login_sub_admin($email,$password);

    if (empty($result)) {
        redirect(base_url());
    } 
    else {  
        $newdata = array(
            'user'  => $result[0]['Employee_Name'],
            'profile'     => $result[0]['Profile_Image'], # New Element
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );

        if (!$this->session->set_userdata($newdata)) {
            echo "Cannot set session";
        } else {
            redirect(base_url());
        }  
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function login_sub_admin($email,$password)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM dc_user WHERE email = '$email' AND password= '$password' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In View**

```
<?php

$user = $this->session->userdata['user'];
if(empty($user))) # or can check logged_in == TRUE (recommended personally)   
{
?>
    <!-- Login -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="sub_Admin" class="nav-item-child radius-3">
            Login
        </a>

    </li>
    <!-- End Login -->

<?php 
}

if (!empty($user)) 
{
    ?>
    <!-- Home -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $user;?>&nbsp;<img style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" class="image-circle" 
            src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profileimages/<?php echo $this->session->userdata['Profile_Image'];?>" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: It says "cannot set session"

Comment: `print_r($result)` in controller and post data

Comment: still not working, print_r result

`Cannot set sessionArray ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 6 [Employee_Name] => Test [Email] => Zaffar@yahoo.com [Contact] => 12457895 [DOB] => 2016-10-22 [Designation] => AC [Password] => 9341604b8acdb726ef2a1011d9c9f56bf3af810e [Profile_Image] => DC.png [Is_Subadmin] => 0 [Is_Hidden] => 0 ) ) `

Comment: change `$result[0]['profile']` this to this `$result[0]['Profile_Image']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150865/discussion-between-msz900-and-abdulla-nilam).

Comment: Why you are returning the result in the model, if I am not wrong then user trying do the login here and as far I know it surely returns the one row if login id is unique. @AbdullaNilam